# Am I working on the same database? getReadableDatabase() throws nullpointerexception

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, nullpointerexception, android-listfragment

I'm new to android programming! I have a MainActivity in which the onCreate looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
    db.onUpgrade(db.getWritableDatabase(), 1, 2); // I have to figure out how to make the app create the database on install and not on app launch

    //Here all tables are filled up. It's hardcoded as the data is not intented to be changed by the user
    String ATABLENAME = "aTableName";
    db.addKeyPoint(new AKeyPoint(1, "sometext", 167, "areference"), ATABLENAME);
    db.addKeyPoint(new AKeyPoint(2, "someothertext", 0, "anotherreference"), ATABLENAME);
}
```

I also have an InitActivity, that launches upon the press of a button. Within this I have a ListFragment that implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks:

```
public static class KeyFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;    

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        // the desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[] { "question1","answer1" };
        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.question, R.id.answer };
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.key_list_entry, null, columns, to, 0);       
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);

        LoaderManager lm = this.getLoaderManager();
        lm.initLoader(1, null, this);

    }

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        final SimpleCursorLoader scloader = new SimpleCursorLoader(getActivity()) {
            @Override
            public Cursor loadInBackground() {
                final DBHandler db = new DBHandler(getActivity());
                Cursor c = db.getKeyPointCursor(1, "Crataegus");
                db.close();
                return c;
            }
        };
        return scloader;
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) { 
        adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);       
    }    
}
```

}

I use the the SimpleCursorLoader with the LoaderManager. It can be found here: https://github.com/browep/AndroidCursorLoaderTutorial/blob/master/src/com/github/browep/cursorloader/SimpleCursorLoader.java . 
In my onCreateLoader the loadInBackGround retrieves a Cursor in the following way

```
Cursor c = db.getKeyPointCursor(anInt, "aTableName");
```

and returns it.

In my databasehandler (db) the getKeyPointCursor looks like this:

```
public Cursor getKeyPointCursor(int keyPointID, String tableName){
    Log.v("bae", "Now in getKeyPointCursor, attempting to get readable database");
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Log.v("bae", "Success... attempting to obtain a cursor");
    Cursor cursor = db.query(tableName, null, KEY_POINTID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(keyPointID) }, null, null, null, null);
    Log.v("bae", "Success... closing db and returning cursor");
    db.close();
    return cursor;
}
```

It prints the "Now in getKeyPointCursor, attempting to get readable database" and then throws a NullPointerException:

```
09-19 19:27:39.920: W/dalvikvm(3055): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c7c1f8)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055): FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:137)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:231)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at jem.danskflora.DBHandler.getKeyPointCursor(DBHandler.java:235)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at jem.danskflora.InitKeyActivity$KeyFragment$1.loadInBackground(InitKeyActivity.java:79)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at jem.danskflora.SimpleCursorLoader.loadInBackground(SimpleCursorLoader.java:1)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:240)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:51)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:40)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:123)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-19 19:27:39.925: E/AndroidRuntime(3055):     ... 4 more
```

I'm suspecting that I'm not working on the same database somehow or maybe that I pass the wrong context to my databasehandler? Anyways I desperately need help to solve this!

Comment: Your suspicion might be true, or not, but nobody can confirm this without seeing the call to `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s constructor.

Comment: Ahh yes thought I missed something quite relevant. I now edited the InitKeyActivity accordingly. Ok?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say that the reason for that exception is this line:

```
private DBHandler db = new DBHandler(getActivity());
```

at that moment `getActivity()` most likely returns `null` as the `Fragment`  isn't attached yet and this `Context` reference is used in the `getReadableDatabase()` and `getWritableDatabase()` methods. Try to initialize the `db` reference from the `KeyFragment` in `onActivityCreated`, the `Activity` reference will be available there.

Also, avoid this:

```
db.onUpgrade(db.getWritableDatabase(), 1, 2);
```

Comment: I now tried that, but then th db is not available for my onCreateLoader function. I've edited the code above, so you can see all of it. As you can see i tried initializing the db on the onCreateLoader function now. It reaches the return c in loadInBackground (and I think it actually returns the cursor), but then it complains about a database being already closed. Hopefully someone can see why? It doesnt finish the initLoader so perhaps something happens here? Does the initloader try to access a db which is already closed somehow?

Comment: @Greforb If you want that `Cursor` to be valid you can't close the database connection, so remove the line `db.close();`.